# I have specific files to install that I have downloaded. Is there a standard practice for location(s)?

Tags: filesystems, package-management

I just downloaded "processing"  for my linux box (ubuntu 14.04), however It was a tarball, but I couldn't run configure on it.

The installation instructions, [found here](http://processing.org/tutorials/gettingstarted/) just say to extract the files and jun ./processing in the folder.

This works fine, but I don't like the folder just sitting in my home dir. I want to make a symbolic link to the processing script found in the folder and put it in /usr/local/bin, but I don't know where I should put the rest of the files.

This is what the contents of the file look like:
[image]

**EDIT:** I ended up putting the directory in /opt and putting a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin.

This works fine for now, but could this cause problems in the future? For example, If I later want to use processing as a library for java, will java have trouble finding the library.

(I am waiting for eclipse to install now and don't have experience in java / package management in general so that may be a naive question)

Answer (score 1):

Try /opt or /usr or /usr/local

All of those are good choices.

As mentioned below in a comment by @Journeyman Geek using the /usr/local location is a generally accepted practice.

Comment: Agree, but [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) says that the purpose of "/usr is shareable, read-only data.". The OP clearly wants to *build* those files. So I'd prefer the practice of unpacking the tarball and building the application in /opt and link in /bin to the relevant files/directories in the /opt directory. I think this complies better with the FHS intentions.

Comment: On the other hand, traditionally you'd just set a prefix and make install would install everything there (resulting in wierd stuff like /usr/local/foo/usr/bin/ and so on). Using /usr/local is a pretty well accepted practice.